# SoapClient debugging

Tags: php, soap, yii, xdebug

I have a PHP project on Yii that calls internal SOAP service (http://mysite/api/hotels). How (and if ) could I initiate and debug the call to the controllers that are behind the API? I know it's possible to pass XDEBUG_SESSION_START to the URI parameter of the web service, but how do I properly construct SoapClient for it? I attempted passing it through $options as array('location' => 'http://mysite/api/hotels/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM) but that did not trigger a first-line breakpoint.

Comment: Are you asking how to debug an API? Shouldn't this be done on the API server/scripts?

Comment: The API is part of the server.. Essentially it's a wrapper/mapper in the Yii - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/topics.webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've decided to pass the parameter XDEBUG_SESSION_START via the URL and that did the job nicely.